# Removing selection markers from JComponents

Tags: java

Is there any way to remove the dotted marker that presents my current selection of a component? 
I've included a picture to show which marker I'm referring to:

[image: Selection marker]

Comment: Be aware that the focus rectangle exists for a reason.  Some users need to use the keyboard instead of the mouse, and keyboard navigation is very difficult without a visual indication of keyboard focus.  Also, that focus rectangle is part of looking and acting exactly like a native Windows app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
tabbedPane.setFocusable(false);
```